# Celery Worker error - Received and deleted unknown message

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to play learn RabbitMQ, I did some basic playing and got things working reading the default celery queue. I then wanted to create a queue and exchange with a routing key.
When defining my queue and exchange with routing_key I get an error, "Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?".
Below is an extract of the code, its gotten a lot uglier because it seems like its not happy with the message, not sure if its headers, currently not using any.

This is the environment file

```
[rabbitmq]
rabbitmq_host=localhost
rabbitmq_port=5672
rabbitmq_user=admin
rabbitmq_password=**********
rabbitmq_exchange=WebhookDev
rabbitmq_routing_key=WebhookDev
rabbitmq_queue=WebhookDev
```

This pushes the message to RabbitMQ

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(
                        rabbitmq_user, rabbitmq_pass
                    )
                    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
                        rabbitmq_server,
                        rabbitmq_port,
                        "/",
                        credentials
                    )
                    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
                    channel = connection.channel()
                    channel.exchange_declare(
                    exchange=rabbitmq_exchange,
                    exchange_type="direct",
                    durable=True
                    )
                    channel.queue_declare(queue=rabbitmq_queue, durable=True)
                    channel.basic_publish(
                        exchange=rabbitmq_exchange,
                        routing_key=rabbitmq_routing_key,
                        body=str(self.request.data),                        
                    )
                    connection.close()
```

this reads the queue and prints it to the console

```
# create celery app with durable exchange and queue
app = Celery('celeryworker', broker='amqp://'+rabbitmq_user+':'+rabbitmq_pass+'@'+rabbitmq_server+':'+rabbitmq_port+'//', backend='db+'+result_backend+'://', 
             task_queues=(Queue(rabbitmq_queue, Exchange(rabbitmq_exchange, type='direct', durable=True), routing_key=rabbitmq_routing_key, durable=True),))

# execute task
@app.task(queue=rabbitmq_queue, durable=True, task_protocol=2)
def execute_task(task):
    print(task)
    return task
```

This is the error I get

```
[2023-05-10 10:57:36,798: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: 'b\'b\\\'{"server_url":"https://xxx.xxx.xxx","event_type":"update","sharedspace_id":5001,"workspace_id":4001,"username":{"id":3001,"type":"workspace_user","email":"xxx@xxx.com"},"data":[{"entity":{"type":"epic","id":"18024","name":"01 - Project Delivery"},"changes":{"description":{"newValue":"<html><body><p>1</p></body></html>"}}}],"isClientConnectionBased":false}\\\'\'' (397b)
{content_type:None content_encoding:None
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'delivery_tag': 17, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': 'WebhookDev', 'routing_key': 'WebhookDev'} headers={}}
```